# Changing rectangle color on click in Python using Tk

Tags: python-3.x, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to get a Tk rectangle created on a canvas to change its color when clicked. Right now, no color change happens when the rectangle is clicked. What do I need to be doing differently?

This is in Python3.5, by the way.

```
from tkinter import *


def set_color(id):
    global alive, colors
    alive = not alive
    col = colors[alive]
    canvas.itemconfigure(id, fill=col)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

alive = False
colors = {True: "green", False:  "red"}

id = canvas.create_rectangle((1, 1, 60, 60), fill="red")
canvas.tag_bind(id, "<ButtonPress-1>", set_color)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a class and create as many instances as you want. http://www.freenetpages.co.uk/hp/alan.gauld/tutclass.htm

```
class OneSquare():
    def __init__(self, can, start_x, start_y, size):
        self.can=can
        self.id = self.can.create_rectangle((start_x, start_y,
                  start_x+size, start_y+size), fill="red")
        self.can.tag_bind(self.id, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.set_color)

        self.color_change=True

    def set_color(self, event=None):
        self.color_change = not self.color_change
        color="red"
        if not self.color_change:
            color="green"
        self.can.itemconfigure(self.id, fill=color)

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=(N, S, E, W))

OS1=OneSquare(canvas, 1, 1, 60)
OS2=OneSquare(canvas, 90, 1, 30)
OS3=OneSquare(canvas, 1, 90, 90)

Button(root, text="Exit", bg="orange",
       command=root.quit).grid(row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

tag_bind sends an event to the function, so "id" is overwritten and now contains the event.  So you can change from

```
def set_color(id):
## to
def set_color(event=None):
```

and it will work because there is only one object/id to deal with in this program. event=None is used because it assigns a default value when no event is sent to the function, as in a button press for example, so will work for all responses.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! And if I wish to have more than one of these rectangles on the screen, how to I bind an event to a particular rectangle?